# SeaglassLookAndFeel issue 2 title bars swing

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, seaglass

does anyone knows when we'll get 2 titlebars?
[image]

Jinternalframe is used with only closable icon and for applying a theme I used this.

Please load seaglasslookandfeel-0.2.jar file and run MainWindow

```
   /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package jsupport.lookandfeel;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

/**
 *
 * @author santoshg
 */
public class MainWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MainWindow
     */
    UserProfile up = null;

    public MainWindow() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        lblUserInfo = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lblUserInfo.setText("Santosh Giri");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(28, 28, 28))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addComponent(lblUserInfo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(242, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addComponent(lblUserInfo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(63, 63, 63)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(162, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    public void disposeUP() {
        if (up != null) {
            up.dispose();
            up = null;
        }
    }
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        if (!lblUserInfo.getText().equals("{}")) {
            if (up != null) {
                up.show();
            } else {
                up = new UserProfile(lblUserInfo.getText(), this);
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No information found about this user, Please contact admin.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>


        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainWindow().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblUserInfo;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

For UserProfile

```
package jsupport.lookandfeel;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

/**
 *
 * @author santoshg
 */
public class MainWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MainWindow
     */
    UserProfile up = null;

    public MainWindow() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        lblUserInfo = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lblUserInfo.setText("Santosh Giri");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(28, 28, 28))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addComponent(lblUserInfo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(242, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addComponent(lblUserInfo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(63, 63, 63)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(162, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    public void disposeUP() {
        if (up != null) {
            up.dispose();
            up = null;
        }
    }
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        if (!lblUserInfo.getText().equals("{}")) {
            if (up != null) {
                up.show();
            } else {
                up = new UserProfile(lblUserInfo.getText(), this);
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No information found about this user, Please contact admin.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>


        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainWindow().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblUserInfo;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Show the equivalent in Metal PLAF.

Comment: Also is it possible to load few UIs from seaglasslookandfeel-0.2.jar like button effect and dropdown? yes then how?

Comment: Set the Look&Feel in the main method _before_ swing gets involved. (remark only)

Comment: Updated, let me know if still it is incorrect

Comment: @Joop I tried, it's not working, I have updated the code as well